# no such table: main.course_name

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

At first it was no such table:teacher_table , read posts told me to uninstall which i did and the the table was created but when tried to insert data in it,i got another error

*Error inserting teacher_password=123 teacher_lname=soukat teacher_email=a@a.com course_id=1 teacher_mobile=12345432 admin_id=1 teacher_fname=galina teacher_no=tr001 teacher_username=mali
  : no such table: main.course_name (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO teacher_table(teacher_password,teacher_lname,teacher_email,course_id,teacher_mobile,admin_id,teacher_fname,teacher_no,teacher_username)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)*
 Unfortunately i did not write any query to create the above table causing the error.

> **SitmDatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class SitmDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String dbName = "sitm_db.db";
    private static int dbVersion =15;
    private final static String dg = "databaseTest";
    public SitmDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion);
        Log.d(dg, "SitmDatabaseHelper: db created");
    }
    //this method when called returns an instance of the helper class

    public static SitmDatabaseHelper getDatabaseHelper(Context context){
        SitmDatabaseHelper instance;

            instance = new SitmDatabaseHelper(context);


        return  instance;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       try{
           Log.d(dg, "onCreate: ONCREATE METHOD CALLED");
           //creating the admin table
           db.execSQL(AdminTable.adminTableQuery);
           db.execSQL(StaffTable.staffTableQuery);
           db.execSQL(CourseTable.courseTableQuery);
           db.execSQL(BatchTable.batchTableQuery);
           db.execSQL(TeacherTable.teacherTableQuery);

       }catch (Exception e){

           Log.d("TableCreation", "onCreate: table creation failed at "+e.getMessage());
       }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
       //dropping older table if exists

        try{
            db.execSQL(AdminTable.dropAdminQuery);
            db.execSQL(StaffTable.dropStaffQuery);
            db.execSQL(CourseTable.dropCourseQuery);
            db.execSQL(BatchTable.dropTableQuery);
            db.execSQL(TeacherTable.dropTeacherQuery);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("dropTables", "onUpgrade: failed to drop table "+e.getMessage());
        }
        onCreate(db);
    }

    @Override //overriden to enable foreign keys
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

> **TeacherTable.java**

```
 public final class TeacherTable {
    //public static final String TEACHER_TABLE,teacherId,teacherNo,teacherFname,teacherLname,teacherUsername,teacherEmail, teacherPassword,
    //
        public static final String TEACHER_TABLE="teacher_table",
        teacherId="teacher_id",
        teacherNo="teacher_no",
        teacherFname="teacher_fname",
        teacherLname="teacher_lname",
        teacherUsername="teacher_username",
        teacherEmail="teacher_email",
        teacherPassword="teacher_password",
        teacherMobile="teacher_mobile",
        teacherDate="teacher_date",
        adminId="admin_id",
        courseId="course_id";




        public static final String teacherTableQuery="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+TeacherTable.TEACHER_TABLE+"("
                +teacherId+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                +teacherNo+" TEXT,"
                +teacherFname+" TEXT, "
                +teacherLname+" TEXT, "
                +teacherUsername+" TEXT,"
                +teacherEmail+" TEXT,"
                +teacherPassword+" TEXT,"
                +teacherMobile+" TEXT,"
                +adminId+" INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                +courseId+" INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                +"FOREIGN KEY("+adminId+")"+" REFERENCES "+AdminTable.adminTable+"("+AdminTable.sId +"),"
                +"FOREIGN KEY("+courseId+")"+" REFERENCES "+CourseTable.courseName+"("+CourseTable.courseID+")"
                +")";



        public final static String dropTeacherQuery = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TEACHER_TABLE;

    }

>**TeacherDao.java ("add method")**
public class TeacherDao extends DBconnectionHelper {
    public TeacherDao(Context tcontext) {
        super(tcontext);
    }

    //add teacher
    public void addTeacher(TeacherModal teacherModal){
        long status;
        //connection
        openWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(TeacherTable.adminId , teacherModal.getAdmin().getSuper_admin_id());
        contentValues.put(TeacherTable.courseId,teacherModal.getCourse().getCourse_id());
        contentValues.put(TeacherTable.teacherNo,teacherModal.getTeacher_no());
        contentValues.put(TeacherTable.teacherFname , teacherModal.getTeacher_fname());
        contentValues.put(TeacherTable.teacherLname , teacherModal.getTeacher_lname());
        contentValues.put(TeacherTable.teacherUsername,teacherModal.getTeacher_username());
        contentValues.put(TeacherTable.teacherEmail , teacherModal.getTeacher_email());
        contentValues.put(TeacherTable.teacherPassword,teacherModal.getTeacher_password());
        contentValues.put(TeacherTable.teacherMobile ,teacherModal.getTeacher_mobile());

          try{
               database.insert(TeacherTable.TEACHER_TABLE, null , contentValues);
          }catch (Exception e){
              Log.d("TeacherTable" , "reason "+e.getMessage());
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

       // close connection
        closeDatabase();
        //return status;
    }
```

> **AddTeacherFragment.java**

```
 public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //DAOs
        coursesDao = new CoursesDao(getActivity());
        teacherDao = new TeacherDao(getActivity());
        teacherDao.addTeacher(new TeacherModal("tr001","galina","soukat","mali",
                "a@a.com","123","12345432",new SuperAdminModal(1),new CourseModal(1)));
       }
```

Comment: I like how some people ask questions as if we were their colleagues at work knowing what is going about;). It will be much helpful if you post relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately i did not write any query to create the above table
>   causing the error.

Assuming that you really meant to say *i did not write any query to use the above table*; you did implicitly by defining ***`teacher_table`*** table with :-

```
    +"FOREIGN KEY("+courseId+")"+" REFERENCES "+CourseTable.courseName+"("+CourseTable.courseID+")"
```

That is to insert into the **teacher_table** the value in the **`courseId`** column must match the specified column (whatever ***`CourseTable.courseID`*** resolves to) in the **course_name** table (i.e. ***`CourseTable.courseName`*** resolves to **course_name**).

However, as the table **course_name** doesn't exist the FOREIGN KEY constraint cannot even be checked. Hence the failure.

You MUST define the **course_name** table and you must also populate it with appropriate values unless you remove the FOREIGN KEY constraint.

Comment: its now working, its true i was implicitly referencing the table column instead of the table name.